# Performance of Sets V.S. Arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I am building a method which constructs and returns a (probably large) array which should contain no duplicate elements. Would I get better performance by using a set and then converting that to an array? Or would it be better to just call `.uniq` on the array I am using before I return it? Or what about using `&` to append items to the array instead of `+=`? And if I do use a set, would not having a `<=>` method on the object I am putting into the set have an effect on performance? (If you're not sure, do you know of a way to test this?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real answer is: write the most readable and maintainable code, and optimize it only after you've shown it is a bottleneck. If you can find an algorithm in that [is in linear time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time), you won't have to optimize it. Here it's easy to find...

Not quite sure which methods you are suggesting, but using my [`fruity`](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) gem:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'set'

enum = 1000.times

compare do
  uniq { enum.each_with_object([]){|x, array| array << x}.uniq }
  set  { enum.each_with_object(Set[]){|x, set| set << x}.to_a }
  join { enum.inject([]){|array, x| array | [x]} }
end

# set is faster than uniq by 10.0% ± 1.0%
# uniq is faster than join by 394x ± 10.0
```

Clearly, it makes no sense building intermediate arrays like in the third method. Otherwise, it's not going to make a big difference since you will be in `O(n)`; that's the main thing.

BTW, both `sets`, `uniq` and `Array#|` use `eql?` and `hash` on your objects, not `<=>`. These need to be defined in a sane manner, because the default is that objects are never `eql?` unless they have the same `object_id` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778354/uniq-of-ruby-array-fails-to-work/8779948#8779948))

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the [Benchmark](http://apidock.com/ruby/Benchmark) library? Tests are usually very easy to construct and will properly reflect how it works in your particular version of Ruby.